# How do I make a function that can calculate something simple if it has an extra argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments

I have a simple function that just multiplies some numbers. It's pretty neat.

```
def multiply(a, b ,c):

    """Just some numbers I want to multiply. Lousy description.
    """
    multiply = a * b * c
    return multiply

print (multiply(2, 5, 6))
```

And the answer, 60, comes out. Pretty straightforward.

But let's say I wanted to multiply four numbers, a, b, c and d, this time. Would I have to repeat what I've written above, but add a "d"? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Have you looked at *args and *kwargs?

Comment: Alternatively, have you used lists before?

Answer (score 1):

```
def multiply(*nums): 
   num = 1
   for i in nums:
      num *= i
   return num
multiply(1,2,3,4) #return 64
```

The * before nums means that this function takes any number of arguments that are going to be stored as a list in the variable nums. Then you can simply iterate through them and get the result.

Answer (score 0):

I have written it in python 2, but the concept remains the same.

```
def multiply(a,b,c):
    multiply = a*b*c
    return multiply

def multiply_args(*args):
    multiply = 1
    for arg in args:
        multiply = multiply * arg
    return multiply
print multiply(2,5,6)
print multiply_args(2,5,6,2)
```

A link for understanding *args and **kwargs: http://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/